# Mock initial viewController - code coverage results

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unit-testing

I've a problem and I don't know the solution even after several hours of try and error and googling and stackoverflowing.

I have a view controller. I would like to pass per dependency injection an object. This object derives from a protocol. In general it is not a problem to setup a unit test. Also mocking works and the unit tests are running. So where's the problem?

I am testing only one class in my primary target. This class has absolutely nothing to do with view controller. But the code coverage is showing me a decent percent value of covering the view controllers. After a while I found out that when I hit the "test" button the project gets executed as if I push the "run" button. And because of that the view controller gets initialized and created and I have no chance to pass another dependency first, or before the tests getting executed.

So I need a method to distinguish between a test run and a real run, to pass in one case a real object and in the other case the fake object.

And my question is, how to to that? I wonder why nobody have this problem. I mean what gives me the code coverage tool if it shows me that methods are covered even though I haven't tested them.

The one and only class that I am testing:

[image: The one and only class that I am testing]

And these are the coverage results (The bars are just gray because Xcode lost focus during screenshot. Otherwise they are blue.):

[image]

So I was expecting to see covered in the results just the class I am testing and not everything else. I know why this problem persists. The view controller has a dependency and this dependency after it gets initialized creates some more classes and so on. What I would like to do is to pass a fake object during unit testing and a real object during a real run. Just like It works in Visual Studio for non ui tests: If the tests are executed the application does NOT start up. The test runner just initialize the subjects under test and that's all. And this is what I want to achieve for iOS unit tests. I guess I've missed sth. very important :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all of us who have or will have the same problem. The solution is to specify environment variables for the test run. After that you can check if you are running your unit tests with code like this (assuming you have created an environment variable called "InTestMode" and set the value to "1" during test run:

```
       let dict = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment

        if let env = dict["InTestMode"] as? String?
        {
            return env == "1"
        }

        return false
```